# Automated mapping between input and output columns of FeatureExtractorFunctions

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

This problem is about FeatureExtraction. It arose in the course of training a neural network where the data contains a mixture of nominal and numeric variables. Basically, my code looks like the following.

```
ncRecidivism = 
 NetChain[{50, ParametricRampLayer[], 50, ParametricRampLayer[], 2, 
   SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> NetEncoder["FeatureExtractor"], 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]]
```

The problem in a nutshell is trying to find a map between the parts of the input before FeatureExtraction and the corresponding parts of the output after FeatureExtraction. I need that mapping in my particular example because if one uses NetPortGradient to find the gradient of an output with respect to the inputs, Wolfram (properly) produces a vector whose length is that of the number of outputs from the FeatureExtractor rather than the number of inputs going into the FeatureExtractor. But, if you can't derive the mapping between input values to the FeatureExtractor and the output values, then I don't see how you can figure out the **meaning** of any gradients of the net's output with respect to the net's inputs, which is what I want to do. And although my issue arises in the neural network context, the issue would seem to arise most times automated feature extraction is performed.

Here's an example where it's easy to figure out the correspondence without the use of programming.

```
fe = FeatureExtraction[{{1.4, "A"}, {1.5, "A"}, {2.3, "B"}, {5.4, "B"}}]
```

If you then run the following code, it's easy to see that the second column in the input corresponds to the second and third columns in the output.

```
fe[{{2.4, "A"}, {3.7, "B"}, {2.4, "B"}}]
```

You could say {1->1,2->{2;;3}} or something like that. But if you have more variables, it isn't obvious to me how to figure out the correspondence. I've been hacking away at Normal representations of the FeatureExtractorFunction and Normal representations of its various parts, but even after going pretty deep, the answer isn't obvious to me.

This is an adaptation repost of a question asked on Community.wolfram.com (https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2401641). Hoping that someone, somewhere has a good answer.

Comment: I believe I can read off from the tooltips of `"Processor" // First@fe` the process by which the output can be de/constructed. There is a key called `"Spans"` in the `MLProcessor` `"MergeVectors"` that indicates the deconstruction. Don't know if that will help in the general case, since I'm not very familiar with these functions.

Answer (score 1):

I went spelunking for some useful utility but I could not immediately find one so I put something together quickly. It's bound not to be perfect.

The main idea is to take the `FeatureExtractorFunction` processor information and graph the feature evolution.
Let's start with your example:

```
fe = FeatureExtraction[{{1.4, "A"}, {1.5, "A"}, {2.3, "B"}, {5.4, "B"}}]
```

and extract the name and input/output part of each processor

```
processor$edges = 
 Rule @@@ Keys@Values@fe[[1, "Processor", 2, "Processors", All, 2, {"Input", "Output"}]]
processor$names = fe[[1, "Processor", 2, "Processors", All, 1]]

(* {{"f1", "f2"} -> {"f1", "f2"}, {"f2"} -> {"f2"}, {"f1", 
   "f2"} -> {"(f1f2)"}, {"(f1f2)"} -> {"(f1f2)"}, {"(f1f2)"} -> {"(f1f2)"}} *)

(* {"Threads", "EmbedNominalVector", "MergeVectors", "DimensionReduceNumericalVector", "Standardize"} *)
```

Now with some replacement we can show how the transformed features are related

```
Flatten@Replace[
   Transpose[{processor$edges, processor$names}],
   {a_ -> b_, name_} :> {Thread[a \[DirectedEdge] name], Thread[name \[DirectedEdge] b]},
   {1}
   ];
Graph[%, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: feature_graph]

This tells us something already but it is not easy to follow the pipeline evolution. In order to do that we need to process the feature names a bit to modify them whenever the feature is processed (the internal representation only modify the name when splitting or merging features)

This code adds a subscript to the feature name that is incremented when the same name appears on both sides of a processor

```
resetIndices := (Clear[index]; index[x_] := 1)
rename[x_List] := rename /@ x
rename[old_List -> x_List] := (rename[#, {}] & /@ old) -> (rename[#, old] & /@ x)
rename[x_, old_List] := Subscript[x, If[MemberQ[old, x], index[x] += 1, index[x]]]
```

I am also going to throw in a couple of functions to style the graph vertices and keep those long processor names from messing up the graph layout

```
labelFeature[x_] := Framed[Style[x, Black], Background -> LightBlue]
labelProcessor[x_] := 
 Framed[Pane[Style[StringReplace[a_?LowerCaseQ ~~ b_?UpperCaseQ :> a <> "\[InvisibleSpace]" <> b]@x,
     Black], {{60}, Automatic}], Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5]
```

This is the updated replacement code

```
resetIndices
edges = Flatten@Replace[
    Transpose[{rename@processor$edges, processor$names}],
    {
     {a_ -> b_, name_} /; Length[a] == Length[b] :> MapThread[
       {labelFeature[#1] \[DirectedEdge] Annotation[labelProcessor@name, "type" -> {##}],
         Annotation[labelProcessor@name, "type" -> {##}] \[DirectedEdge] labelFeature[#2]} &,
       {a, b}],
     {a_ -> b_, 
       name_} :> {Thread[
        labelFeature /@ a \[DirectedEdge] Annotation[labelProcessor@name, "type" -> {a, b}]], 
       Thread[Annotation[labelProcessor@name, "type" -> {a, b}] \[DirectedEdge] labelFeature /@ b]}
     },
    {1}
    ];
```

And this is the new graph

```
Graph[edges,
 VertexShapeFunction -> Function[{center, name, size}, Inset[name, center]],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> Function[{pts, name}, {Arrowheads[{{.01, 0.6}}], Arrow[pts]}],
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}
 ]
```

[image: detailed_feature_graph]

In order to track what happens to individual feature components this will have to be expanded a little but I believe the current version of the code is already useful for getting some insights.